# Show Fbwebdialog with friends already checked

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-3.0

i'm trying to send invite from a game, but I want to pre-check some users according to some criteria. According to facebook tutorial, I can do this using parameter 'to' with some user ids. But this way, the user loses his chance to change my suggestions of friends and send to other ones.
This is the code that I'm using now, which sends a request to a specific friend. But as I said, user can't change the users to send.

```
- (void)inviteFriends {

    NSString *facebookID = @"100003355638755";
    NSMutableDictionary* params =
    [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObject:facebookID forKey:@"to"];

    NSString *message = @"SOME_MESSAGE";
    NSString *title = @"TITLE";

    [FBWebDialogs presentRequestsDialogModallyWithSession:session
                                                  message:message
                                                    title:title
                                               parameters:params handler:
     ^(FBWebDialogResult result, NSURL *resultURL, NSError *error)
     {

     }];


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Get a brand new view controller, fetch user's facebook friends in there, populate the table view with those friends, pre-check the one's you're suggesting (probably by moving them on top of the list and displaying a different UI for them, or maybe a section header "Suggested invitations" and another one for generic "Friends on Facebook"), add a button to process the web dialog invitation to selected friends (possibly as a navigation bar item) and you'll have a fully customizable Facebook invitation mechanism.

Comment: I got the idea. But can you provide an example, please?